# Is the time complexity of querying an indexed column O(1)?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

Let's suppose that table `A` has a column named `X` which is numeric and indexed.

If the query is something like:

```
find all rows where X is greater than some value
```

Is the time complexity of retrieving the result O(1)?

In other words, it does not matter whether table `A` has 1 million rows versus 10 billion rows?

Question 2:

Let's suppose that table `A` has another numeric column `Y` which is numeric and indexed.

If the query is now:

```
find all rows where 
X is greater than some value
AND
Y is smaller than some value
```

Would this query take twice as long as the first query?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague questions, let me break it apart to several cases.

Firstly nothing is O(1), regardless of how you're fetching your data you always need to scan a complexity that's relative to the size of the data.

Case 1 - no indexes that support the queries exist.

In this case no matter what query you use Mongo will perform a "collection scan", this means all data in the collection will be checked to see if it matches the query. or in complexity terms O(N). this is true for both queries hence overall the complexity is the same.

Case 2 - an index exist that satisfy's both queries ( { x: 1, y: 1 } ).

In this case Mongo will perform an "index scan", this means it will scan the index trees (btrees) instead of the entire collection, giving you a logarithmic complexity, I'm not entirely sure on the exact complexity of this as it depends on the way Mongo choose to write these things, but overall it should be O(t log(n)) for query 1. because a compound index nests tree indexes this means the complexity for query 2 should be the same times some constant.

Now we can answer both questions:

> In other words, it does not matter whether table A has 1 million rows versus 10 billion rows?

Obviously it matters, the time complexity for each search is the same regardless of scale but in real life terms this greatly matters as O(1M) != O(1B) even if the ratio is the same.

> Would this query take twice as long as the first query?

This is a little harder to answer, and I would argue it's more dependant on scale than anything else, for case 1 (colscan) and smallish scale it will probably run in around the same time. The best way for you to answer this is to run your own benchmarks that match your usecase.